# How to fix App Clip launch experience using an NFC tag?

Tags: ios, ios14, apple-appclips

I've setup an App Clip launch experience using an iPhone 7 running iOS 14.2 and built using Xcode 12.2 RC.

My goal is to launch the App Clip using an NFC tag, but that doesn't seem to work correctly. When using the native NFC Tag Reader in the control center the spinner spins indefinitely, but never opens the App Clip. However, scanning the same exact URL through a QR code using the native QR code scanner opens the App Clip without problem.

This video shows the issue in action https://youtu.be/sobDXKLCTP0

Is this a known issue? Did I make a mistake in the configuration, knowing that the QR code scanning works as expected? I've seen videos demonstrating this feature working correctly but only using newer iPhones that support background NFC scanning.

Comment: Very interesting. Did you try opening a ticket to Apple, or even better, posting in the developer forum?

Comment: I have not, should I?

Comment: Sure. They answer in the forum

Comment: Are you sure both the QR code and NFC tag decode to the same invocation URL? Does that same invocation URL work when received via Messages from another iOS 14 device? If it doesn't, it may be because the page at that URL does not contain the required app clip metadata for the Smart App Banner. Metadata on that page is NOT required for app clip QR codes, but is required for Messages. I'm not sure if it's required for NFC tags...

Comment: @ScottyB I am sure that they are both the same URL. I'm not sure about Messages, so I could give that a shot. I'm sure that it's not required for NFC tags, since I followed this tutorial and it did not require anything on the web-side other than the associations file https://youtu.be/_hNNDRR2Ldg

Comment: Have you tried using a 3rd party iOS NFC tag reader app to make sure your phone can read it? I saw a comment on the YouTube link "I found that there are some types that the iphone does not read."

Comment: @ScottyB I have. Both iPhones and Android devices read the tag properly. For example, if I change the URL to something else, I get a popup to bring me to Safari. However, when the URL exactly matches the one configured in the Local Experiences, the NFC reader simply spins forever

Comment: Then I would ensure that the invocation URL works as an app clip when received via Messages. If it works there, I would contact Apple Developer Support with your case. If it doesn't, I would think the metadata at the URL's page needs to be changed to fix both problems.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue @Ferdz , did you end up solving it?

Comment: @MatthewPatience I have not. I reported this issue to Apple and have had no feedback yet

Comment: @Ferdz I just heard back from ADTS and they confirmed it is an issue and have now asked me to submit an official bug report. I also discovered that this issue only exists for iPhone's that don't have background NFC reading capabilities. This is why you noticed it on your iPhone 7 and I did on my iPhone 8. If you try it on an iPhone XS/R or later you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: @MatthewPatience that's good. I had a hunch that it was only on devices that do not support background scanning, but lacked the devices to validate. I have already submitted a report but please keep me updated if you get any news on yours, since I haven't heard back from them

Answer (score 0):

I am new to the app clip & NFC Tags things. But I think you should check the NFC Tag type. Because, if your website have the meta data for the app clip, then the nfc tag should work fine. I used NTAG 213 NFC Tags with 144 byte memory that I bought from amazon.com. see here: https://www.amazon.sa/dp/B07P9DT7Z6/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apip_9nUYQegsGHtIo. Important to know that I tried to use the tag on iPhone 8 Max but got no response. It worked great on iPhone 12 Pro.

Comment: It isn't related to the NFC tag as far as people can tell. It's the iPhone. Only the iPhones that support background NFC scanning appear to work properly